# nodejs accessing a variable inside a callback method

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, scope, callback

How can I access the variable inventory outside the callback?
I would like to access it and return it.

```
loadInventory = function () {

var inventory = [];

offers.loadMyInventory({
    appId: 730,
    contextId: 2,
    tradableOnly: true

}, function (err, items) {
    items.forEach(function (item) {
        inventory.push({
            asset_id: item.id,
            market_name: item.market_name
        });
    });
    //Not accessible here
});
};
```

Comment: //Not accessible here is within the callback in the above,

Comment: Can you share working code so I can execute it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need loadInventory to take a callback, that whatever calls it would pass:

```
loadInventory = function (callback) {

var inventory = [];

offers.loadMyInventory({
    appId: 730,
    contextId: 2,
    tradableOnly: true

}, function (err, items) {
    items.forEach(function (item) {
        inventory.push({
            asset_id: item.id,
            market_name: item.market_name
        });
    });
    callback(inventory);
});
}; 

loadInventory(function(inventory) {
  console.log(inventory);
});
```

Comment: That solved it, thanks

Comment: Can you mark it as the answer then?